# How to blockquote text in one go

Tags: text-editing

With this text:

```
Play with it a few times you will see my point. The 
command you need is:

$ echo hello
```

How do I make it into:

```
> Play with it a few times you will see my point. The
> command you need is:
>
> $ echo hello
```

Without using the complicated regular expression:
`M-x replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^` <kbd>RET</kbd> `>` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Note that I couldn't use `C-M-%` shortcut key to conjure `query-replace-regexp` since it's not possible to produce that key combination in a terminal.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `string-rectangle` (`C-x r t`).

Set a mark (`C-SPC`) before the first character of the first line,
move the cursor until the first character of the last line,
use `C-x r t`, then type `>` and ENTER key.

Answer (score 3):

If you do this a lot, you can utilize `comment-region`.  Essentially, add a hook to your mode that sets `comment-start` to `>`, then add a key binding for `comment-region` (in `c-mode`, for example, it's `C-c C-c`).  This has the benefit of being reversible with `uncomment-region` as well:

```elisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (require 'newcomment)
              (make-local-variable 'comment-start) ;; Always make buffer-local
              (setq comment-start "> ")
              (local-set-key "\C-c\C-c" #'comment-region)))
```

Comment: BTW, @peer-gynt thanks for the idea, I just put this in my own `.emacs`! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the region to be quoted using `C-SPC` if in Text mode and use `M-;` which is bound to `comment-dwim` and that will prompt you for a "Comment syntax" which you can then enter `>` in the prompt.

After using `comment-dwim` to prefix the lines, you may also find `M-q` which is bound to `fill-paragraph` useful for wrapping the lines of the block quote if you're not interested in preserving the original line length.

Alternatively, if you have `markdown-mode` installed, you can use `M-x markdown-mode` to switch to it, and then mark the region you care to quote and use `C-c C-s q` which is bound to `markdown-insert-blockquote`.

Finally, if you really want to use `query-replace-regexp` from a terminal which I've found sometimes fails to work due to the combination of Ctrl, Meta, and Shift keys all requiring to be pushed at the same time, you may find it works using  the following sequence `Esc` then `C-%`. The `Esc` key is essentially a "meta lock" key which will hold down meta for the duration of the next key sequence.